# How to count the number of objects created in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In the following code snippet i have created 4 instances of CompanionClass and want to know how many
instances i have created , so have tried many ways but didn't work. Here i used companion object class
to keep track of objects but i know it has no connection with objects because keepTrackOfObjects() is
static. Can anyone help me solve this, please?

```
class CompanionClass
{
     
    companion object{
        var numberOfObjects = 0 
        fun keepTrackOfObjects() = println("number of created objects currently is: +
             ${++numberOfObjects}")
    }
}

fun main()
{
 
    val obj1 = CompanionClass()
    CompanionClass.keepTrackOfObjects()
    val obj2 = CompanionClass()`enter code here`
    val obj3 = CompanionClass()
    val obj4 = CompanionClass()
    CompanionClass.keepTrackOfObjects()
}

// output is
// 1
// 2
```

Comment: Create a list of objects, then counting them is not hard (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections-overview.html)

Comment: where are you doing numberOfObjects++ in your code?

Comment: @Luuk i don't need to create list of objects. Suppose i need one or two objects and want to know how many objects of class i have created. can you help me without lists.

Comment: @hfarhanahmed inside the companion object class.

Comment: The problem is companion object{
        var numberOfObjects = 0 } runs every time when a new instance is created. this counter should be in another class to retain the previous value.

Comment: @hfarhanahmed you are right bro. every time i create a new instance the numberOfObjects reinitialize and set to 0 that's why i can't keep track of objects.

Comment: I am posting it as a proper answer, mark it right so everyone else can get benefit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `init` block to count the elements you created:

```kotlin
class CompanionClass {
     
    companion object {
        var counter: Int = 0
        
        fun counter(): Int {
            return counter
        }
    }

    init {
        counter++
    }
}
```

You can test the behavior in this [kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/QS1cXz24o).

Comment: I tried your code snippet and created several object of CompanionClass. When i print CompanionClass.counter() it gives me 0 as output and the same is true for obj.counter().

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your companion Object,

```
var numberOfObjects = 0
```

will initialise the variable every time you create a new instance. So create this variable in a separate class where keep all static content and use it from there. then you companion object will be like this.

```
    companion object{
        fun keepTrackOfObjects() = println("number of created objects currently is: +
             ${++numberOfObjects}")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you should increment your numberOfObject in a `init` statement.. Get a look at the code below

```
class User (var firstName:String,var lastName:String){
    companion object {
        var numberofinstance:Int = 0
        fun getNumberOfInstance() = println("Nombre d'instance = $numberofinstance")
    }
    init {numberofinstance++}
}
```

Now you can use it in your main function

```
fun main(){
    val user1=User("bob","marley")
    val user2=User("bonkey","reynard")
    val user3=User("jobbs","steve")
    val user4=User("bill","naim")
    val user5=User("jeff","romain")

    User.getNumberOfInstance()
}
```

Output : `Number of instance = 5`

Comment: Beware this approach, and all the others until now, are not Thread-Safe.